# Can't unlock certain GUI system settings + unusual authentication notifications on login and power off

Tags: permissions, login, users, settings, administrator

I am running a recent upgrade to 20.04LTS.  I am not using the Ubuntu on Wayland session as it won't recognise my login; I'm therefore logging into the Ubuntu session.

Since the upgrade there are a number of behaviours (that might be connected) that are vexing me.

When I tried to delete an old printer and add a new one I found that I couldn't unlock through the GUI in **Settings > Printers**.  The unlock button is greyed out and mouseover pops up **system policy prevents changes. Contact your system administrator**.  This behaviour is also the same on **Settings > Users** and **Settings > Date & Time**.

I have been able to workaround with `sudo system-config-printer` but I'm a pretty novice/casual Ubuntu user and prefer to use a GUI as my go to option.

I'm not sure if this is also related behaviour, but also kicked off straight after upgrading to 20.04.  When I log in, I get multiple prompts saying **Authorisation required** and this is both to **refresh the system repositories** and **create a colour profile**.  I can either key my login password in multiple times for them to eventually stop popping, or I can cancel them out; I haven't noticed any change in my session as a result of either repeatedly entering password or repeatedly cancelling them out.

When I go to power down or refresh, I also get a single authorisation prompt (which I never used to before the upgrade) and then a notification that two other users are still logged in.  Those users are both my user profile (which may be related to the multiple authorisation prompts upon login).

I have no idea if these problems are related, but they all seem to have to do with permissions/authorisation.  My user profile show as being administrator and my groups are:

```
[username] adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev netdev lpadmin sambashare plex chrome-remote-desktop
```

Based on some similar (unsolved) queries in forums I have run the following commands, and according to forum answers they don't seem to be out of whack (although as a casual user I can't be sure).

Running `id` shows the following:

```
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username)
groups=1000(username),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(netdev),113(lpadmin),128(sambashare),130(plex),1001(chrome-remote-desktop)
```

Running `ps -ef | grep [p]olkit` shows the following:

```
ps -ef | grep [p]olkit
root         926       1  0 09:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
```

I am physically logging in at the terminal and not remotely.

Any advice would be very gratefully received.  Even if that advice ends up being to reinstall an earlier version or do a full system rebuild.

Comment: For the purposes of diagnostics, you can create a new user, add the user to sudoers, and log into that user to see if the problems persist. If the problems have to do with the current user, you can migrate to the new and remove the old

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep policykit-1-gnome`  please.

Comment: ii  policykit-1-gnome                                           0.105-7ubuntu2                             amd64        authentication agent for PolicyKit

Comment: @Nmath thank you, that's very helpful.  I'm keen to directly fix the problem w/current user, if only as a learning process.  However, your suggestion sounds eminently better than a complete rebuild.